# How to check if a string contains another string but a character can vary?

Tags: swift

I don't really know how to explain this so well but let's say I have a string called "Hello World". I want to check if the string contains "HeXXo World". So basically the l's can be different in the string but it would still return true. Sorry that I'm not explaining this well. I'm somewhat of a beginner in swift.

Comment: Do you have some code you have tried by now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression `"He[a-z]{2}o World"`. This would require any two lowercase letters between `e` and `o`:

```
let sentence = "Hello World"
let pattern = "He[a-z]{2}o World"
if sentence.range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression) != nil {
    print(true)
}
```